# SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED and SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED not working?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to detect, when the size of a SDL2 window changed. But neither SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED nor SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED are working, at least on MacOS. 
This is my code:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, 0, 0);

bool running = true;
SDL_Event event;
while (running) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            running = false;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
            return 3;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {
            return 4;
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
}
SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
```

When running the program and resizing the window nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Edit: I looked up the documentation on window events(https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent). 
It says to write something like this:

```
event.window.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED
```

But this also isn't working.

Comment: You've already found documentation, but messed it up. It is `event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED`.

Comment: Thanks, could you write this as answer, so that I can close this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SDL_WINDOWEVENT_*` are not event types but [SDL_WindowEventID](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID). That is, if your `event.type` is `SDL_WINDOWEVENT`, you can access `window` union field for extra data, including `event`, e.g.

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
        if(event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```